# Tensorflow: What is the difference between having several feature columns and having one feature column with several dimensions?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm trying to get started with TensorFlow with a simple `tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor`. My data set is a time series where I want to use the steps at `T-n, ..., T-1` as features and `T-0` as the label. All values are floats, so naturally I thought I would turn each time step into a `real_valued_column` feature.

However, these columns have a `dimension=` attribute, and in an example with the Iris data set on the TF website [they use](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn#construct_a_deep_neural_network_classifier) a single column with four dimensions as the feature. I would have thought that here too each of the four attributes (sepal width/length, petal width/length) should have become it's own feature and thus it's own `real_valued_column`. Is my understanding wrong? What's the difference between these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Each flower is represented by its four attributes,so your feature matrix indeed has 4 columns.But to train the classifier,you can't take each feature on its own,since they are probably correlated to the class the flower belongs to.So the dimension is set to dimension = 4.Think of the real_valued_column as a set of columns(their number being the dimension)which form a feature matrix.

Comment: Do you have a link that explains this in more detail? I wasn't really aware that there is a difference between the number of features and the dimensions, I would have thought that one feature == one dimension of the training samples.

Comment: There is no difference between number of features and dimensions.If you have 4 columns,you have 4 features so dimension = 4 as I said. The only way things could get a bit more complicated is if each FEATURE is represented by a vector with its own dimension.Unless that's the case,feature = dimension.